# Error al intentar cambiar distintos graficos

Tags: python, django, chart.js

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion la cual muestra los datos creados en un grafico de chartjs, lo que estoy realizando lo hace bien, pues se muestran todos los datos en la forma que deseo, pero tengo un problema y es que ahora estoy intentando hacer que segun el tipo de grafico que un usuario desee este se cambie, el problema es que el grafico se cambia pero en caso de tener multiples graficos solo se cambie el primer grafico los demas siguen con el grafico por defecto, este es mi template:

```
<select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChart()" data-role="select">
    <option value="pie">pie</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<canvas id="{{ project.slug }}" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Este es mi script:

```
var faltante = 100 - {{ project.porcent }};

var data = {
    labels: ['{{ project.name }}', 'Falta'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [{{ project.porcent }}, faltante],
        backgroundColor: ['#252850', '#f44611']
    }],
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('{{ project.slug }}').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
});

function updateChart() {
    myChart.destroy();
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: document.getElementById("chartType").value,
        data: data
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola, que exactamente no está funcionando? entiendo por el código que según se vaya cambiando un select se cambia el tipo de gráfico no? al cambiarse el select no cambia el gráfico o lo cambia sin datos?

Comment: lo que pasa es que un grafico se crea por cada dato guardado en la base de datos, pero cuando ingreso a la funcion updateChart el objeto myChart solo toma los datos de una sola grafica